# How to get Synapse analytics delta table load path?

Tags: delta-lake

How load delta table in Synapse using delta table path?
Use Synapse Optimize command `optimize {tablename}`

Comment: It can be done using optimize and then table name command in sql format

Comment: describe detail {table name}